# GlassFish Server start failed. check username and password

Tags: glassfish

What can be the reason for this error in Apache NetBeans IDE 17?

`Deployment error: <html>GlassFish Server start failed<br/>Please check server admin user name and password properties.<br/>Also please check the server log file for other possible causes.</html> See the server log for details.`

I restart the server. and then do the build and clean. but in the deploy phase this error message displayed.  what is that username and password that mentioned in the error message??

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The user and password is needed by Netbeans to deploy the application after GlassFish server starts. This looks like Netbeans is configured to use a different user and password than GlassFish accepts. Did you change admin and password on GlassFish after you installed it? You can try removing GlassFish from Netbeans and adding it to Netbeans again.